# Vector Calculus involving the dot product

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

The question states that if $v$ = constant, then $\vec v$ (a vector) and $d\vec v/dt$ (referring to the vector v) are perpendicular (unless $\vec v$ or $d\vec v/dt =0$).

I know if two vectors are perpendicular, then there dot product is $0$. Other then that, I do not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: If v is constant then its derivative is zero no? Then you are in the (unless ...) part.

Comment: I think they are different v's. the v=constant is one v and the v and dv/dt are in boldface indicating a vector.

Comment: This notation is confusing and does not show in your current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt} (\vec v \cdot \vec v) =0 \implies 2(\vec a \cdot \vec v )=0$$

where $\vec a = \frac{d \vec v}{dt}  $

Answer (score 0):

Exploit what you know, and express the perpendicularity:

$$\vec v\cdot\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=0.$$

Integrating over time,

$$\int \vec v\cdot\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\int\frac12\frac{d\vec v^2}{dt}=\frac12 \vec v^2=C$$

(the formula works for vectors as for scalars).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to present a case of rotation. If a vector v is constant in length while having a derivative means that the "velocity" is perpendicular to the vector. This is nicely exhibited by the first answer.